# "Errno::EACCES  in Main" when I updates my CSS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Errno::EACCES in Main#index

Showing /var/www/dgwanxin.net/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

Permission denied - /var/www/dgwanxin.net/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2F13fe41fee1fe35b49d145bcc0661070520111031-27669-y64i1u.lock

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Wanxin</title>
5:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
```

I don't know why this happened. I'm running Linode, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1 onUbuntu 11.04 and Nginx. It started when I uploaded a CSS file, replacing what was there before.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the access rights to directories, directory owner and owner group.

Comment: 'drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 10-26 00:55 dgwanxin.net
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 10-26 00:54 app
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 10-26 00:54 assets
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-27 02:31 controllers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-27 02:31 helpers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-26 00:54 mailers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-26 00:54 models
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 10-27 02:31 views
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-27 03:23 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-27 02:31 javascripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 10-30 05:07 stylesheets'
Is it right?Thanks.

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 356 2011-10-30 04:47 application.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 322 2011-10-27 03:23 index_cont.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 903 2011-10-30 05:07 layout.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175 2011-10-27 02:31 main.css.scss`

Comment: I'am not sure for nginx, but passenger requires a owner www-data with group www-data for access to application files. If owner is root, than nginx cannot get an access to files. Please try to chown your files like chown -R www-data:www-data <your ::Rails.root>

Comment: Thank you very much!I used "sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/dgwanxin.net/public" and "sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/dgwanxin.net/tmp" resolved this!!

Comment: I am sorry.when I uploaded a CSS file,my web had next problem!`Error compiling CSS asset
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied -/var/www/dgwanxin.net/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2F8f973eb6109609de635e58cdae454a6a20111101-12628-1kwx5r4.lock
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:330:in 'mkdir'`

Comment: A nginx.conf should contain a line 'user www-data;'. And all files/dirs in your rails root folder should have an owner www-data, not only public or tmp. Now i will think again about probably reasons of such behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I had launched the Rails server using the command

```
rvmsudo foreman start -p 80
```

(I use the above so that I don't have to type in 5000 as the port name every time I access my site)

INSTEAD OF

```
foreman start
```

After using rvmsudo, and then trying to go back to NOT using rvmsudo, I got the same error message you got.

A quick fix for me was to go back to always using rvmsudo. Another potential fix that might work would be to delete the whole cache folder.